# Can not read property 'match' of null

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, cloudant

[image]I am facing this issue in my node-red debugger console. I am new to this and am not sure why I am getting this on both cloudant nodes that I have added. Is there any specific format that I should follow when passing data to the cloudant? Or is there any instructions that I should address?

I tried creating different instances and adding that credentials to the  cloudant node. This is the error that i am facing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
```

`payload: 
"akhil.raj@gmail.com", 
topic: "disable service", 
date: "2019-08-07T14:22:37.000Z" , 
header: { 
   object attachments: array[0],
   _msgid: "d5eca677.ab5308", 
   temppayload: "Disable service"
  }`

This is the paylord that i am getting

Comment: without sharing anything confidential or personal, are you able to share what is in msg.payload as it is passed to the clouding node?

Comment: ***payload: "akhil.raj@gmail.com"
topic: "disable service"
date: "2019-08-07T14:22:37.000Z"
header: object
attachments: array[0]
_msgid: "d5eca677.ab5308"
temppayload: "Disable service↵"***

It is a collection of objects

Comment: It might be clearer if you update your question with the `msg.payload`, because I think you meant `payload: {"akhil.raj@gmail.com", topic: "disable service", date: "2019-08-07T14:22:37.000Z" , header: { object attachments: array[0],  _msgid: "d5eca677.ab5308",  temppayload: "Disable service"}}`.  It looks wrong around `array[0]`, but is difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid json object. Is `"akhil.raj@gmail.com"` a key or a value? If its a key then it should look like:

```
msg.payload = {
  "akhil.raj@gmail.com" : {
    topic: "disable service",
    ...
  }
}
```

If its a value then it should look like:

```
msg.payload = {
   email: "akhil.raj@gmail.com",
   topic: "disable service",
   ...
}
```

You should also make use of the debug node to actually see what `msg.payload` looks like.

I think you have `msg.payload = "akhil.raj@gmail.com"`, which is not a valid json object, and will be rejected by cloudant as you try to add it to the database.

Comment: `payload : "akhil.raj@gmail,com",
topic: "disable service"`  it is like this payload is a key and the id is the value.

Comment: Are you saying that `msg.payload = "akhil.raj@gmail.com"` ?

Comment: I just added an image to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: As you have it `msg.payload` is not a valid JSON object. So will be rejected by Cloudant.